# Remove Unix user named postgres after complete uninstallation of postgresql

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, unix

I'm running MX Linux 21 and recently installed PostgreSQL-13; I wanted postgres to have read, write and execute access to a certain folder therefore I added the unix user `postgres` to the group of owner and granted such accesses to the group. The commands was: `setfacl -R -m u:postgres:rwx myfolder`

Then I uninstalled postgresql from MX package manager completely (i.e., `sudo apt remove postgresql-13`).

I thought the unix user called `postgres` should be gone with the removal of postgresql, it however was not the case. I am still able to do `sudo su postgres` and logged in as the user `postgres`.

I then did `sudo deluser postgres` and it failed with exit code 8, saying there's process still running on `postgres`.

I then did a `ps -ef` and found that `sudo su postgres` is the main process that held up the deletion of user `postgres`. I killed that process in `htop` and ran `sudo deluser postgres` again with success.

But when I checked with `getfacl` to see if the unix user `postgres` has been deleted from the user group, I found this:

```
$ getfacl myfolder
# file: owner
# owner: owner
# group: owner
user::rwx
user:121:rw-
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

That `user:121` is in place of user `postgres`.
Does this mean installing `postgres` is leaving a trace in my system and I can't purge it?
Does this mean installing `postgres` would always make an user `postgres` in my system and if I don't delete it, it'll be there forever?

Comment: I decide not to delete this question, nor to get moderator to do so (unless they do this by chance); this question'll stay for @Schwern's accommodation and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean installing postgres is leaving a trace in my system and I can't purge it?

`apt remove` deletes what is installed from the package, but not files created such as configuration or databases. `apt purge postgresql-13` should get those. As a last resort, you can delete the files manually.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove

> even if I managed to delete the user postgres, there's a user:121 in my system

There is no user:121, there are only files and directories owned by user ID 121 which may or may not exist. `postgres` *was* user 121.

Run `users` to see the users on your system.

Comment: Thanks; I wasn't trying to delete the files, please let me know which part wasn't clear I'll edit it. I was trying to understand why the user `postgres` didn't go with the uninstallation of postgresql; and even if I managed to delete the user `postgres`, there's a `user:121` in my system.

Comment: @stucash There is no user:121, there are only files owned by user ID 121.

Comment: right so there was a trace that some user:121 came by before and owned some files in the past, is this correct?

Comment: @stucash Yes. Try `apt purge` and see if that cleans everything up. You might have to reinstall postgres and then purge. But it will not touch files in your home directory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarificaiton, I think you are right I'll have to reinstall and do a purge on it.

Comment: it seems the better way to remove user `postgres`, in case of `setfacl`, is to remove its permission to any spefici folder/file first by `setfacl -x user:postgres`, then we can just use `sudo deluser postgres` to remove the user; this'll clear up everything